# How can I instance this array along the curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, instances

I have created a ball chain to wrap around my object and to do this i added one uv sphere and then added a nurbs circle, array and curve modifier. The problem is that naturally each sphere add more to the poly count and in this case it takes up a good 30-40K tris. Since this is for a game asset and i need to keep it as low as possible, is there a way to instance the sphere around the chain?[image]

[image]

Comment: you have 40 spheres and you say that they make a total of 40k tris, which makes 1k tris per sphere, it seems a lot, can't you use spheres with a lower count of faces? Also I don't think that the instancing tool or modifiers like Array are compatible with game engines